# In XML, creating an attribute once and use it many times using VBScript

Tags: xml, vbscript, xml-parsing

I need to add **same attribute** to **different nodes**. Is there a way to define the attribute **once** and use it **many** times ?

Here is what I tried to do:

```
Set myAttribute = xmlDoc.createAttribute("operation")
attribute.value = "delete"
```

Now I can do the following:

```
node.attributes.setNamedItem(myAttribute)
```

But if want do add the same attribute to another node, I get an error. Like:

```
node2.attributes.setNamedItem(myAttribute)
```

So, is there a way to **re-use** the attribute **without repeating** the *first two lines of code*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, `myAttribute` variable is an object reference so it points to same all the time. You need to clone the node. Have a look at [cloneNode Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms762269%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

```
Set xmldoc = CreateObject("msxml2.domdocument")
    xmldoc.loadXML "<root/>"

Set theElement = xmldoc.createElement("element")
Set theAttribute = xmldoc.createAttribute("attribute")
    theAttribute.value = "delete"

For i = 1 To 15
    With xmlDoc.documentElement.appendChild(theElement.cloneNode(True))
        .attributes.setNamedItem(theAttribute.cloneNode(True))
    End With
Next

WScript.Echo xmldoc.xml
```

output (indented and prettified manually):

```
<root>
  <element attribute="delete"/>
  <element attribute="delete"/>
  <element attribute="delete"/>
  <element attribute="delete"/>
  <element attribute="delete"/>
  <element attribute="delete"/>
  <element attribute="delete"/>
  <element attribute="delete"/>
  <element attribute="delete"/>
  <element attribute="delete"/>
  <element attribute="delete"/>
  <element attribute="delete"/>
  <element attribute="delete"/>
  <element attribute="delete"/>
  <element attribute="delete"/>
</root>
```